# Does a UITableView have to be visible (not hidden) for a change to accessory type to be rendered?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I have a UITableView which I am trying to sync w/ a grid (AQGridview) by showing either a "list" or "grid" view.

When the list (UITableView) is visible (hidden=NO) the following code updates the accessory type correctly, i.e., a checkmark is displayed.

```
if (state) {
  cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
} else if (cell.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark) {
  cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
}
```

When in the "grid" view w/ the list hidden and the user selects a cell in the grid the accessory type for the corresponding list cell is updated using the exact code above. When the user switches from the grid to the list view (grid setHidden:YES, list setHidden:NO) the corresponding list cells that have an accessory type of checkmark do not have a checkmark displayed.

Does the UITableView not update the cells when it is hidden? If so, do I need to [tableView reloadData] when the list is shown?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you either want to have some sort of refresh at viewDidLoad or as you mentioned do a [tableView reloadData] whenever the action to hide/view the table kicks off.